# Authentication to Azure Active Directory and receive AADSTS90019 error

Tags: c#, authentication, azure-active-directory

I am trying to authenticate against AAD using the following code:

```
 string userName = "something.com"; //(just an example)
 string password = "IafksdfkasdaFadad=asdad=a="; //(just an example)
 string clientId = "6cd6590f-4db9-4c6b-98d1-476f9e90912f"; //(just an example)
 var credentials = new UserPasswordCredential(userName, password);
 var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/common");
 var result = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://api.partnercenter.microsoft.com", clientId, credentials);
 return result;
```

and I got AADSTS90019 error: No tenant-identifying information found in either the request or implied by any provided credentials.

As a remark, it is just a console application made in Visual Studio using C#.

Based on the information from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-aadsts-error-codes the explication for AADSTS90019 error is: **MissingTenantRealm - Azure AD was unable to determine the tenant identifier from the request**.

So, my question is: What is the tentant identifier and how should I use it in my request?
Should it be the one from the following screenshot? The screenshot is made from the Azure account.

[Azure Application Overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8EHS.jpg)

Any information can help.

Thank you.

Comment: Right now, you are using `common` which is for both Organization and consumer accounts. You can try with mentioned tenant to see what is the behaviour. So in that case, your authority would be `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/v2.0`.

Comment: If it is a partner Organisation, whould it be possible to connect without the tenant?

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize your authentication context with a tenant-specific authority instead of common:

```
var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/your-directory-id");
```

Replace `your-directory-id` with your Directory (tenant) id.

Answer (score 0):

```
var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/common");
```

Here Replace the string "common" with the tenant name.